# pointers not read correctly

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, printf

I am trying to get name of the input, output, and data files from the array for further processing. However, I am getting a weird error or problem. So, my program is not reaching the for loop. It does not even print the statement before the for loop. However, I tried using the debugger and the program is correctly printing step by step. So, when I run it does not print and when I debug step by step it prints. That is Weird!

```
char *method;
        method=malloc(25);
        method=NULL;
        char *dataFileName;
        char *inputMethod;
        inputMethod=malloc(25);
        inputMethod=NULL;
        char *inputFileName;
        char *outputMethod;
        outputMethod=malloc(25);
        outputMethod=NULL;
        char *outputFileName;
        char *commandArray[]={"if=q.txt","of=output.txt"};
        char**args=(char**) malloc(sizeof(char*)*256);
        args=commandArray;
        int i;
        printf("Before second for");
        for(i=0;i<2;i++)
       {
            printf("I am here");
            if(*args[i]=='d')
                {
                    method=strtok_r(args[i],"=",&dataFileName);
                    printf("The method given is %s",method);
                    printf("Data File Name is %s",dataFileName);
                }
                else if(*args[i]=='o')
                {
                    outputMethod=strtok_r(args[i],"=",&outputFileName);
                    printf("The output method given is %s",outputMethod);
                    printf("output File Name is %s",outputFileName);
                }
                else
                {
                    inputMethod=strtok_r(args[i],"=",&inputFileName);
                    printf("The input method given is %s",inputMethod);
                    printf("Input File Name is %s",inputFileName);
                }
            }

        if(method==NULL)
        {
                dataFileName=malloc(256);
                printf("Please Enter A File Name");
                scanf("%255s",dataFileName);
                printf("%s",dataFileName);
        }

        if((inputMethod==NULL)||(outputMethod==NULL) )
        { 
            char* array[]={"stdin","stdout"};
            if(inputMethod==NULL)
                inputMethod=array[0];
            if(outputMethod==NULL)
                outputMethod=array[1];
        }
```

I am developing using Netbeans in C. The above code is written inside main. Thanks!

Comment: Please start with reading a C book. There are so many basic errors in your "code" presenting lack of understanding fundamental concepts in C.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? One step you allocate memory to pointers and in next line you make them point to `NULL` and then again allocate memory .

Comment: I know I tried a lot of tweaks to make this thing run somehow, but still could not figure out. That's the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i intentionally left the previous answer because understanding memory allocation is trivial in programming in c specially. and as i see you have a big issue with that.

but still you have issue in nearly every thing. in my actual answer, i will try to simplify you how to use strtok, to split string and parse it. i guess this is the second main problem with your code.

the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void){
    char commandArray[][256]={
        "if=q.txt",
        "of=output.txt"
    };

    char infile[256], outfile[256];

    for(int i=0; i<2;i++){

        char *ptr,*cmd;

        cmd=commandArray[i];
        ptr=NULL;

        printf("parsing command '%s'\n",cmd);

        cmd=strtok(cmd,"=");
        ptr=strtok(NULL,"=");

        if(!cmd){
            printf("Error parsing the string '%s'\n",commandArray[i]);
            exit(1);
        }

        if (strcmp(cmd,"if")==0){
            strcpy(infile,ptr);
        }
        else if (strcmp(cmd,"of")==0){
            strcpy(outfile,ptr);
        }
        else{
            printf("unknow token '%s'\n",cmd);
            exit(1);
        }
    }


    printf(
        "\n\n"
        "input file: '%s'\n"
        "output file: '%s'\n"
        "\n\n",
        infile,outfile);

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes the problem solved when I allocated memory right before the assignment!

Answer (score 0):

the main problem is this:

```
char *method;
method=malloc(25);//allocating space for 25 char
method=NULL; // throwing up the allocation without freeing it;
             // now the allocation is lost
             // now method is useless (it is null)
```

Comment: It's a big problem, but I'm not sure it's the *main* problem. There are so many other big problems.

Comment: i didn't yes analyzed the code. that pointer just jumped to my eyes.